# Stop recursion printing

Tags: java, recursion

I am somewhat new so please have patience. 
I've seen the following on a YouTube video:

```
public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
            index++;
        }
    }

    public static long fibonacci(int i) {
        if (i == 0) return 0;
        if (i <= 2) return 1;
        long fibTerm = fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);
        return fibTerm;
    }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to get this to stop printing after 5, 10, 15, 20 or even 25 numbers?

Comment: Yes it's possible.  `break;` out of the `while` loop once `index` has reached the desired number.

Comment: `while(index <= 25)` ?

Comment: This is also a terribly inefficient algorithm for solving fibonacci. You can use dynamic programming to make it significantly faster. http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs490/sec202/notes/dp/DP%201.pdf

Comment: A word of advice. Don't use `while(true)` until you know the how this actually works. Just like this case you might end up in infinite loops

Comment: @Cruncher, solving a fibonacci is a classic example for introducing method recursion, in begginers introduction to programming. I doubt the OP would be asking this kind of question if he was actually trying to find an optimal way to print the fibonnaci sequence.

Comment: @jwatkins, using recursion for fibonacci nummer is the classic **wrong** example of recursion. It's trivial to do it without recursion and using recursion here is wrong on soo many levels.

Comment: @Cruncher, I do agree with you on that point. But that is something that should be argued with those who write tutorials, not with first-time programmers that follow them.

Comment: @jwatkins I was just providing info xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commonly you would do something like

```
while(index < 20) {
```

Comment: I love you <3. That is all.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the "while" loop by a "for" loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int numberOfIterations = 25;
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfIterations; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
    }
}
```

This is exactly what "for" loops are used for: loop a certain number of times, then stop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
        index++;
        if (index == 25) { //stop after having printed the 25th number
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop appears to have an improper sentinel.

Comment: `while(index < 25)` is the proper way. This is really silly code.

Comment: @Johan: well sure, but i figured this would be more instructive - make the least possible change to do what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

And yes, you can have that stop printing numbers after n numbers are printed, and its pretty easy.

```
while (index < n)
{
    System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
    index++;
}
```

This is what is causing it to print, and since your Boolean value (true or false) is ALWAYS true, it will loop forever. This can be fixed by replacing the "true" in `while (true)` with a boolean statement. I.e: `while (index < n)` where n is the maximum number of numbers to print (5, 10, 15, 25, etc.)